# custom styling for checkbox with input within label

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to create a custom style for a checkbox. It works normally until I place the `input` within the `label`.

Does anyone know how to get the CSS working?

```css
input[type=checkbox] { /* to hide the checkbox itself */
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    color:green;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before { /* unchecked icon */
    content: "";
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before { /* space between checkbox and label */
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}
    
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { /* checked icon */
    content: "✔";
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { /* allow space for check mark */
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="c2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
    <p>hello</p>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an `<p>` inside your label, right next to the `input` you can use that to apply the `pseudo`-element instead:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + p:before {
  display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    color: green;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + p:before {
  content: "✔";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + p:before {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="c3">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cc" />
  <p>hello</p>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS references `input + label`. `+` is the adjacent sibling selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors So that means it is targeting a `label` that comes directly after an `input`.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/* to hide the checkbox itself */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  content: "";
}
/* unchecked icon */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
/* space between checkbox and label */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: "✔";
}
/* checked icon */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
/* allow space for check mark */
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2">hello</label>
```

Comment: sorry, I need <label><input></label>. its because the label  accordion nested inside

Comment: @BenjaminOats as far as I'm aware, you can't without javascript. CSS can't traverse back up the chain, so a nested `input` can't affect it's parent's CSS.

Comment: NP. If you need help doing it with JS feel free to change your question and I'll do that, it's pretty easy.